# How is minimum required account balance calculated?

Tags: transactions

Here's a transaction:

```
0xf8900b8504a817c800830f424094394b88b676f289224bdc332f361be399ea064bd587060a24181e4000a4a358c2fa841a3c2efd182abc0a149b32a493044d84aa6c0d4ebe34e0f1b9e96403db65da2aa0a2b453bcade87566a292462a6e4de82615508de982936799642dba9e959b1ac3a0364eee7341bf901182e59c1b7492b03e55163703435fc8a1f199fcf30d50abca
```

Here's the result of parsing it with `helpeth` library using `parseTx` method:

```
Signed by: 0x4f33d4895b0584f31024132468bd85beb4249ac5
Nonce: 0x0b
To: 0x394b88b676f289224bdc332f361be399ea064bd5
Value: 1700000000000000 (0.0017 ETH)
Data: 0xa358c2fa841a3c2efd182abc0a149b32a493044d84aa6c0d4ebe34e0f1b9e96403db65da
Gas limit: 1000000
Gas price: 20000000000 (20 Gwei)
Potential total transaction cost: 0.02 ETH
Minimum required account balance: 0.0217 ETH
```

When I send this transaction to the network I pay **0.0027 ETH** (almost ten times smaller than `Minimum required account balance`).

The transaction cost is calculated with this formula:

`value + gasPrice * gas = txCost`

In my case its: 0.0017 + 0,00000002 * 50 000 = **0.0027**

How does `Minimum required account balance` calculated?

And why there's need for it at all? It's very confusing when want to send a tx and have enough balance, but get an error `unsufficient funds` when balance is lower than the `Minimum required account balance`

Answer (score 1):

The "Potential total transaction cost" means "Maximum tx fee" which is:

`gas limit` * `gas price` = 0.02 ETH

So, "Minimum required account balance" is the above + `value`